# KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL' in django 1.4

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a project on Django 1.4.3 and try to set up on my mac. But raise an error

`KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'`

**settings.py:**

```
DATABASES = {'default':  dj_database_url.config()}
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

**environ config for database:**

```
os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/viggo_backend'
```

Comment: Where do you set environ? Why don't you set in your environment and not in your code?

Comment: you can set os.environ at settings file too ..

Answer (score 0):

In terminal i have to do

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/viggo_backend
```

Comment: You have posted a question and then posted an "answer" that isn't really an answer to your question. This should be part of the question?