# DATABASE_URL Heroku key error

Tags: heroku

I enter the following code to connect to my heroku database using Python:

```
urlparse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database=rul.pat[1:],
    user=url.username,
    password=url.password,
    host=url.hostname,
    port=url.port
)
```

I get a key error on the second line.  Can someone describe what is happening? Do I need to add the DATABASE_URL to the environment somehow?  I am running the Linux bash on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL' in django 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836781/keyerror-database-url-in-django-1-4)

in the terminal I typed something like this:

```
export DATABASE_URL=<url to database>
```

Comment: Note: I have to do this with ever instance of bash.  It does not remember this value.